# Inspect Request Headers and Payload for a external request in Flask route

Tags: flask, python-requests, http-headers

I am relatively new to using Flask and the requests library. I have a route in my Flask app, and the route uses the requests library to call some external API.  When I inspect the request headers (using Postman), I can only see the request headers for the Flask route (i.e. `/sendData`).  Is there a way for me to inspect the request headers and payload of the call to external API as well, **using Postman or the browser**?

Thank you in advance!

```
@app.route('/sendData', methods = ["POST"])
def handle():
  // Do something

  // Making a call to external API
  res = request.post('https://externalapi', data)

  return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to inspect the request headers and payload of the call to external API as well, using Postman or the browser?

The short answer is: **No**

But that does not mean you can not inspect them at all. It depends on what you want to inspect them for, and how often you need to do it. *(in order of complexity)*

1. You can print/ log the headers and payload for the request in Flask and view it in the console
2. You can run Flask in debug mode in an IDE and add a breakpoint before the request and inspect the request being sent.
3. You can use a network analyzer like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to sniff the packets sent (you may not get the payload while using HTTPS)

There may me more methods, I will add them as I get it.